# SQL Server Pivot on this data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, pivot-table

I'm having a rough go trying to pivot my data :(  It is dynamic data and structured like this:

```
|    Date    |    Source    |    Amount    |
--------------------------------------------
| 12/1/2016  |    Source1   |      $0      |
| 12/1/2016  |    Source2   |      $2      |
| 12/1/2016  |    Source3   |      $5      |
| 12/1/2016  |    Source4   |      $4      |
```

There can be unlimited sources and I want to pivot it by source/date:

```
|    Date    |    Source1    |    Source 2    |    Source 3    |    Source 4    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 12/1/2016  |    $0         |    $2          |    $5          |        $4      |
```

Something like that, anyway.

I have tried coding a lot of ways, so I'll just put in what I thought it could be:

```
SELECT     myDate , Source, Amount
FROM         mydb

PIVOT
(max(source) FOR source IN (select distinct source from mydb) as myPivotTable

WHERE     (myDate > @StartDate)
```

of course, that doesn't work.  This was going to be part of a stored procedure, just not quite there.  Was hoping to pivot on that data so I can do some line trends in SSRS.

I also followed another example and tried this:

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(source) 
                    from mydb where myDate > @StartDate
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
```

And then tried to use that in the place of the "select distinct".  However, the sources are text and that didn't seem to do much for me.

Comment: I am waiting for the dynamic pivoter to show up.

Comment: @GurwinderSingh You make me giggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple Dynamic Pivot on Source

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName([Source]) From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
Select  @SQL = '
Select [Date],' + @SQL + '
From YourTable
 Pivot (sum(Amount) For [Source] in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
Date        Source1 Source2 Source3 Source4
2016-12-01  0       2       5       4
```

Now, If you want Source to be sequenced Like Source 1, Source 2  it would require just a minor tweak

FYI the generated SQL would look like this

```
Select [Date],[Source1],[Source2],[Source3],[Source4]
From YourTable
 Pivot (sum(Amount) For [Source] in ([Source1],[Source2],[Source3],[Source4]) ) p
```

Comment: @GurwinderSingh What can I say, I'm bored and I REALLY don't want to clean the basement.

Comment: I am still learning how to do it. May be one day I'll do it before you :P. +1

Comment: @GurwinderSingh  I don't believe that to be true.  I've seen the quality of your answers.

Comment: I've worked mostly on Oracle. so, tsql is new to me. I am working on it to get better.

Comment: That wasn't what I needed and I went a different route, but it is an answer and probably could work.